# Defining a sum on the elements of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematica-online

I am interested in defining the quantity $$H=n-1-\sum_{i\ne j} R_{ij}, $$where $R$ is a random $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix (as a side question: how should I go about adding the condition $\rm{Tr}(R)=1$?). I start with

```
a[n_Integer] = Table[RandomComplex[], {n}, {n}]
R = (1/2) (a + ConjugateTranspose[a])
MatrixForm[R]
```

to generate the matrix, but the line

```
H[n_Integer] := n - 1 - Sum[R[[i,j]] Boole[i!=j], {i,1,n}, {j,1,n}]
```

isn't working at all. As a complete beginner I'm having trouble with spotting any mistake. What goes wrong?

Comment: You can get the total of all elements and then remove the diagonal.

Comment: Yes, that also makes sense, but `H[n_Integer]:=n-1-Sum[R[i,j],{i,1,n},{j,1,n}]-Tr[R]` also doesn't work for me. Is there a function to sum all the elements directly?

Comment: Look at Total to sum the elements.

Comment: `Total[R]` only sums along the columns, though...

Comment: Then either apply Total twice or use the optional second argument to choose the level at which to sum: Total[R, 2]

Comment: `H[n_Integer]:=n-1-Sum[R[[i,j]],{i,1,n},{j,1,n}]-Tr[R]` you need double brackets.

Comment: That does make sense. Thanks for the tips. Do you have any idea how to add the condition of having a unit trace when generating the hermitian matrix?

Comment: @yarchik You are right, I forgot to type them. Apparently my problem is the definition of $H$ as a function of $n$: `n-1-Total[Total[R]]` works fine, but `H[n_Integer]:=n - 1 - Total[Total[R]]` gives an error...

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[symmetrize, mR, h]
symmetrize = (1/2) (# + ConjugateTranspose @ #) &;

mR[n_Integer] := Module[{a = symmetrize@RandomComplex[1 + I, {n, n}]}, a/Tr[a]]

h[m_] := Length[m] - 1 - Total[MapIndexed[Drop]@m, 2]
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1]

r = mR @ 3;

TeXForm @ MatrixForm[r]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0.561874\, +0. i & 0.102843\, -0.0725292 i & 0.45773\, -0.0262951 i \\
>  0.102843\, +0.0725292 i & 0.165912\, +0. i & 0.102042\, +0.0178369 i \\
>  0.45773\, +0.0262951 i & 0.102042\, -0.0178369 i & 0.272215\, +0. i \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
Tr @ r
```

> 1.+ 0. I

```
Abs[Tr @ r]
```

> 1.

```
h @ r
```

> 0.674769 + 6.93889*10^-18 I

```
SeedRandom[1]

h[mR[3]]
```

> 0.674769 + 6.93889*10^-18 I

**Update:** ***"my ultimate goal is to plot a function of h f[h[m***]] as a function of n."_

```
ClearAll[hmR]
hmR[n_] := h@mR[n]

SeedRandom[1]
hmR[3]
```

> 0.674769 + 6.93889*10^-18 I

```
flist = {Re, Im, Total[ReIm[#]] &};

Row[Table[DiscretePlot[f[hmR[n]], {n, 2, 10}, Frame -> True, 
   ImageSize -> 1 -> 20, PlotLabel -> f], 
  {f, flist}], 
  Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: @kgrl, thanks for the answer. I can't say I understand everything you've written, but it works fine. However, I still have an issue: my ultimate goal is to plot a function of $h$ `f[h[m_]]` as a function of $n$. It is not immediately clear to me how to make the code you wrote work to do this...

Comment: @TotalNoob, please see the update.

Comment: thanks again for your help. I have actually asked another question to deal with the plot, at [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215149/plotting-an-integer-valued-function). I'll look into your code right away and see what I can understand.