# Plotting an integer-valued function

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the quantity $$H=n-1-\sum_{i\ne j} R_{ij}, $$where $R$ is a random $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix with trace $1$. The code that generates it was kindly provided by a user in another question of mine:

```
ClearAll[symmetrize, mR, h]
symmetrize = (1/2) (# + ConjugateTranspose @ #) &;

mR[n_Integer] := Module[{a = symmetrize@RandomComplex[1 + I, {n, n}]}, a/Tr[a]]

h[m_] := Length[m] - 1 - Total[MapIndexed[Drop]@m, 2]
```

My objective is to define the quantities $$\tau_1=\frac{\pi\hbar}{2H},\quad \tau_2=\frac{\pi\hbar}{2\Delta H} $$ where $\Delta H=H(n-H)$ and plot $\max(\tau_1,\tau_2)$ as a function of the dimension $n$.

This is my naive approach to the code:

```
delta[m_]=h[m]*(Lenght[m]-h[m])

tau1[m_]:=(Pi*\[HBar])/(2*h[m])
tau2[m_]:= (Pi*\[HBar])/(2*delta[m])

DiscretePlot[Max[tau1[m], tau2[m]], {Lenght[m], 0, 1000}]
```

I don't get any errors, but the plot turns out to be empty. Any tip on how to solve this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: hbar needs a value, and Length needs to be spelled correctly.

Comment: hbar is interpreted as $\hbar$ in the editor, so it does have a value.                                            @Bill, I forgot to add the lines that actually generate the matrix and $H$, namely             
`r=mR@3` and `h@r`. However, still no dice!

Comment: also in the `DiscretePlot` command, `Length[m]` should be `m`.

Comment: hbar does not have a value.  You can evaluate `tau1[500]` to see that.

Comment: @BillWatts Not quite, as I am interested in plotting with respect to $n$ rather than $m$. In short, fix a matrix with such and such conditions, and plot in various dimensions the quantity $\max(\tau_1, \tau_2)$.

Comment: Well `Plot` requires a variable there, so `Length[m]` won't work.

Comment: The result will depend on the distribution from which you draw your matrices `R`. As your problem looks like quantum mechanics, I'd recommend drawing the matrices from a [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure), i.e. a measure that is invariant under unitary transformations, which yours is not.

Comment: Firstly, you are right that $\hbar$ doesn't have a value. I searched for it online and apparently it is implemented as "PlanckConstantReduced" but I can't figure out how to actually input it in the notebook...

Comment: Secondly: how do I tell the program to plot the function as `n=Lenght[m]` varies from 1 to an arbitrary number? That is the whole point of the question.

Comment: Can `R` be anything or should it be positive semi-definite?

Comment: Actually yes, it should be positive semi-definite as it is supposed to represent a random pure quantum state.

Comment: You can assign $\hbar$ a value as with any other variable.

Comment: For positive semi-definite random Hermitian matrices with unit trace, drawn from a Haar measure, I'd recommend something like `R[n_Integer?Positive] := #/Tr[#] &[#.ConjugateTranspose[#] &[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, n, 2}].{1, I}]]`.

Comment: @Roman does this line work with the rest of the code as it already is?

Comment: @TotalNoob yes it should be a drop-in replacement that enforces positive-semidefiniteness. Just try it out. Playing with formulas is the only way to become an expert.

Answer (score 1):

I think that $0\le1+\sum_{i\neq j}R_{i,j}\le n$, and so you have $0\le H\le n$. This means that both $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are unbounded.

The extreme cases for $H$ come from the following matrices:

- For `R = ConstantArray[1/n, {n, n}]` you'll find $H=0$.
- For `R = SparseArray[{{1,1}->1/2, {1,2}->-1/2, {2,1}->-1/2, {2,2}->1/2}, {n,n}]` (for example) you'll find $H=n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean exactly by unbounded? $\max(\tau_1,\tau_2)$ is supp.osed to represent a time interval

Comment: "Unbounded" means there can be values all the way up to infinity. Just look at what happens for `R = ConstantArray[1/n, {n, n}]`: you'll have `H = 0` and therefore $\tau_1=\tau_2=\infty$. For the other extreme example I gave, you have a finite $\tau_1$ but you still have $\tau_2=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you want, but I do get a plot with:

```
\[HBar] = 1

DiscretePlot[Max[tau1[mR[n]], tau2[mR[n]]], {n, 0, 1000}]
```

[image]

You can set $\hbar$ to its real value if you want.

Comment: Thank your for your answer - it really doesn't look very good. I'll look into the code and see if there is something to change.